# URLFOR Visual force page not populating Parent Account

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to overriding a Standard button on a custom object.
Unable to populate Account field.  It just populates the value I enter but not the parent Account Name.

```
<apex:page standardController="Big_Box_Products__c"
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Big_Box_Products__c.New, null, ['Name'='Big Box Product','cancelURL'=URLFOR($Action.Account.Tab,$ObjectType.Account),'CF00N2F000000aroL'='Account__r.Id'], true)}" />
```

Comment: try: `<apex:page standardController="Big_Box_Products__c"
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.Big_Box_Products__c.New, null, ['Name'='Big Box Product','cancelURL'=URLFOR($Action.Account.Tab,$ObjectType.Account),'CF00N2F000000aroL'=Account__r.Id], true)}" />` . no quotes required around the sobject.field as SFDC will resolve this as part of the formula evaluation. That said, URL hacking doesn't always have access to lookup object fields. I have had in the past had to create an artificial cross object formula field on Account

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Tried the syntax and it gives a very general error: Error: Syntax error

Comment: Is there another alternative to pre-populating the Account and Record Name field instead of the url hack?

Answer (score 1):

From a custom button, (type = URL, not VF), I got the following to work (this is a Classic solution as URL hacking is not allowed in LEX)

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Foo__c.New,null,[Name='Big Box',CF00N2F000‌​000aroL= Foo__c.Account__c ])}
```

Notes:

- Quotes around the parm names are not required; SFDC parser is smart enough to realize values on the left side of `=` are keys, not values.
- Fully-qualified object.field name required to reference values from the standard controller as merge fields for your lookup field.

Comment: yes I think syntax wise this will work in a Custom button for the custom object.  The reason I was using the VF page was to override the standard 'new' button.  This Custom object is related to an Account Object.  When  a user scrolls down to the Custom Object they need to be able to create a new Custom Object that is related to the Account.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I got the button to show but the Account field is still not populating.  Is your Account field a simple lookup?

Comment: Yes, simple lookup

Comment: Tried to mirror your syntax and its telling me I am missing a right bracket. `{!URLFOR($Action.Big_Box_Products__c.New,null,[Name='B‌​ig Box Product Added',CF00NE0000002aLV0= Big_Box_Products__c.Account__c])}`

Comment: It is a direct copy-paste from my Custom Button, try selective reduction to narrow down the problem item